# DoThrow MailException with mockito

Tags: testing, junit, mockito, jakarta-mail

I have a class JavaMailDao that i want to test using JUnit and mockito. I want to test the Catch part

```
try {
            this.mailSender.send(msg);
    } catch(MailException ex) {
            throw new BackendException(DaoExceptionType.EMAIL_ERROR);
}
```

In the test i have this:

```
Mockito.doNothing().doThrow(new MailException()).when(this.mailSenderMock).send(Mockito.any(SimpleMailMessage.class));
```

The problem it's it says : "can't instantiate the type MailException", and i have the import too by the way.

```
mport org.springframework.mail.MailException;
```

Does anyone know how to do it? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MailException` is an abstract class. Abstract classes cannot be instantiated, so instantiate one of it's subclasses, such as `MailSendException`.

Solution:

```
Mockito.doNothing().doThrow(new MailSendException("Test message")).when(this.mailSenderMock).send(Mockito.any(SimpleMailMessage.class));`
```

See [the Spring Framework docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mail/MailException.html) for more info and suitable subclasses.